# How to have multiple scheme as an array in app.json for an Expo app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, mobile-development

Do you have any idea on how to make an expo app to have multiple schemes like an array of strings? Currently they only support scheme as a string https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/de31ca319b23d07fb6a62cbe08e57ddc45ce6c78/packages/%40expo/config-types/src/ExpoConfig.ts#L159

We need our app to support multiple schemes, like

`scheme1:// scheme2:// scheme3://`

We did try setting it up in `app.json` like this,

```
scheme: ["scheme1", "scheme2", "scheme3"]
```

but, we have eas updates setup. So, whenever we run `eas update` we got `scheme should be a string error`

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur5R0.png)

We also tried setting up the intentfilters and CFBundleURLTypes for schemes. The problem is that only the first scheme is being use. Other schemes specified does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to talk with a dev from the Expo team. Here's the PR
https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/22324